# I want to install Netbeans 8.0.1 in my laptop

Tags: windows-10, installation, java

I have already installed JDK v12 in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12. When I run my netbeans installer, it says JDK 7 or newer is required for installing the Netbeans IDE. Make sure that the JDK is properly installed and run installer again. You can specify valid JDK location using -javahome installer argument. What to do? When I typed -javahome in command prompt, it says '-javahome' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This should come *after* your install command. For example: `command -javahome`

Comment: Netbeans 8 doesn't support JDK 12.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen so, what should I do? I am total noob in this,

Comment: Just download and install JDK 8. Then run NetBeans with it. Should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Many Java based programs like Tomcat require JAVA_HOME to be set as environment variable to work correctly. Please note JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK directory not a JRE one. The point of setting the environment variable is to let programs know in which directory executables like javac can be found.

We can try to set java environment variables in windows 10 according to [How to set JAVA_HOME in Windows 10](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10)

It includes the following three steps:

1. Open Advanced System Settings and set JAVA_HOME Environment variable.
2. Update System PATH
3. Test your configuration

For details we can refer to the above article.